# search not returning matches I want with ngram filter

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

My elastic search setup is something like this

```
         :analyzer => {
            :default => {
              :type => "custom",
              :tokenizer => "whitespace",
              :filter => ["lowercase", "standard", "my_ngram"]
            }
          }
```

where my_gram is specified like this

```
            :my_ngram => {
              :type => "nGram",
              :min_gram => 1,
              :max_gram => 20
            }
```

The problem is that when I search for something like "cre" im getting "crib" as a result as well as "crew" and "remember" ... which appears like its matching on 're' and 'cr' ... I want it to be an exact match for 'cre' inside the word if there is a match.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this ... just specify `:default_operator => AND` in the `query_string` options. So something like this (using Tire gem, because I'm lazy)

```
    Post.search do
      query { string your_query_string_here, :default_operator => "AND" }
    end
```